# dygraph not atdjusting for large data points

Tags: dygraphs

dygraph is supposed to automatically adjust to fit all points on the chart. I have a chart which is mainly in the 80-100 range, however when I add a point that is around 300, the chart is not resized to fit the larger point in. Instead, I see two lines going off the edge off the chart - obviously the point is outside the chart display area.

How can I make dygraph automatcally fit all points on the chart
I create a chart like this:

```
                chart = new Dygraph(e, chart.data,
                {
                    drawAxesAtZero: true,
                    includeZero: true,
                    yRangePad:20,
                    drawPoints: true,
                    colors: ["#ffFF00"],
                    labels: ['X', 'Y']
                });
```

It seems to me like a huge bug in the basic chart functionality - maybe I will have to keep track of the highest and lowest data points myself and reset the range when they change.

Ridiculous I know, but the current workaround I have is to recreate the chart when a new largest value is added to the chart.

Comment: Take a look at `updateOptions(attrs, block_redraw)` [here](http://dygraphs.com/jsdoc/symbols/Dygraph.html#updateOptions). The javascript example [dynamic graph](http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/dynamic-update) may also help you. what happen if you call something like `g.updateOptions( { 'file': char.data } );` ? Look at [options](http://dygraphs.com/options.html) such as `valueRange` too.

Comment: This problem shows up in the jsfiddle example you gave - except it is a problem on the x axis. New points that are added are not actually on the chart - they are off chart and you only see them later when the next point is added
I am seeing the same problem with the Y axis, except because I don't ever get any larger points, I never see those points

Comment: I don't know if you noticed, but the jsfiddle example uses fixed ranges, not calculated ranges - so the bug would not show up in this example anyway

Comment: @tyujrer, can you provide a working example via dygraphs.com/fiddle which demonstrates the problem? Your pseudocode isn't enough to tell what's going on.